# Jenkins/Groovy move variables out to a config file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I've been asked to move some variable from a Groovy script out into a configuration file. I'm fine using something like :-

```
readFile('../xx-software.cfg').split('\n').each { fileName ->
        sh "wget ${theURL}${fileName}"
      }
```

However, even though I have added xx-software.cfg into the same directory as my Groovy script it does become available for use within that groovy script.

I hope this makes sense!?

How can I move my variables out into a config file to make it easier for the application support team to make future edits without changing the code?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches you could use.

Firstly, file format for the configuration and how to read the data into variables. You could use Java Properties format, YAML or JSON and these are all handled by the [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps) plugin with steps [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md). You can read the file with these steps:

- readProperties
- readYaml
- readJSON

Next problem, how to get the file available to your pipeline so it can be read from the workspace using these steps. Possibilities are:

- In source control with your pipeline code. It can be fetched with the pipeline.
- In a separate source control for configuration, your pipeline will need a step to fetch it.
- Use the [Jenkins Config File Provider plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider). It has a step to provide a config file managed in Jenkins.
- Provide it as a Custom Tool zipped archive from a binary server like Artifactory. You can use custom tool definition pipeline steps to make this available to the pipeline.

The Config File Provider option might provide any easy way to have a file that can be updated, but there won't be any version control of it.

Comment: It's the "fetched with the pipeline bit" I'm stuck with. As far as I can see you can only grab one Jenkinsfile under the script path of the Pipeline section in the job config. Can anyone tell me how to fetch more than one file with my pipeline?